# Building OpenCV cmake error: could NOT find PythonInterp

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, cmake

To build OpenCV, I ran this in the terminal in my ~/opencv/build directory :

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/opencv-3.0.0/build -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
-D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers -D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/path/to/opencv_contrib-3.0.0/modules ../
```

But no matter what happens, I see this error in the Traceback : *(Could NOT find PythonInterp:*)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.11", 
but required is at least "3.4" (found /usr/local/bin/python)
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.11", 
but required is at least "3.2" (found /usr/local/bin/python)
```

**Further down the line, this shows up**

```
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.11)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 NO
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:
```

The correct output should look somewhat like this:
[correct Python Interp output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKI1r.png)

I have tried everything, but this keeps coming up!
In essence, I cannot build OpenCV properly, and hence cannot install it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, b.enoit.be!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error talks about not being able to find numpy, so install numpy:

```
pip install numpy
```

In addition, change your include directory to make sure you are actually including it. For the `PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR`:

```
-D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
```

Then, run `make clean`, and delete your `/build` directory, and run your `cmake`, then `make` again.

Comment: Do you have `numpy` installed?

Comment: I don't think so...how do I go about that?

Comment: Do `pip install numpy`, then try recompiling opencv.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if this sounds noob, but I should run that in my home directory, correct?

Comment: Doesn't matter where you run it

Comment: Did you do "make clean" and deleting your /build/ directory before running cmake, then make, again?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the path to each version of Python manually. 
[image]